# InvalidArgumentError : indices[6,0] = 88140 is not in [0, 10000) [[node functional_5/embedding_4/embedding_lookup

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am a beginner in tensorflow and Keras.I have seen others have posted similar questions. I try to fix but still error

```
#Install
pip install --upgrade tensorflow

#Import
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from typing import Dict, Text
import tensorflow as tf
%matplotlib inline

# Ratings data.
df_ratings = pd.read_csv("ratings.csv")

nmovieId = df_ratings.movieId.nunique()
nuserId = df_ratings.userId.nunique()

#movie input network
input_movie = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[1])
embed_movie = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nmovieId,15)(input_movie)
movie_out = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embed_movie)

#user input network
input_users = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=[1])
embed_users = tf.keras.layers.Embedding(nuserId,15)(input_users)
users_out = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(embed_users)

# Concatenates
conc_layer = tf.keras.layers.Concatenate()([movie_out, users_out])
x = tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(conc_layer)
x_out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='relu')(x)
model = tf.keras.Model([input_movie, input_users], x_out)
```

## Fitting using a list of inputs

```
hist = model.fit([Xtrain.movieId, Xtrain.userId], Xtrain.rating, 
                 batch_size=64, 
                 epochs=5)
```

The error I get while trying into fitting the model is as follows.

```
InvalidArgumentError:  indices[6,0] = 88140 is not in [0, 10000)
     [[node functional_5/embedding_4/embedding_lookup
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your data. A total number of movies or users is 10000. But one of your records has `.movieID` or `.userID` of 88140.